# Jquery redirect with Ajax Calls to another page Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am trying to implement two pages. The first page being a selection of the items I want to show on the second page.

On my first page, I have done a selection of the items which I want to render.

On click of a button, 1. the ids of these items will be placed in an array and 2. the user will be redirected to a new page through:

```
window.location.replace("/schedule");
```

Right now, I want to achieve the following:

Do an ajax call through rails to get each of the array items. i.e. make an ajax calls to the urls of myclass/[id]. The id belonging to the items in the array.

I am not sure how I could get my array items from the current page to the next page or if there is a better way of achieving this. Any advice or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it advisable if I do not redirect the page but instead just hide the divs for selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:remote => true` to your form. Then, app will render your `action_name.js.erb` view instead of `action_name.html.erb`. In js file you can put code, which will repleace div without redirection, f.e.

```
$('#div_id').html('<%= escape_javascript render(your_partial_name) %>');
```

You don't need to do anything special in partial and controller action, its all the same.

Comment: It was not exactly what I am asking but I did render the 2 pages on the same page with div hiding so thanks.